# No hats related to Christmas?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash-2014

I think there should be some Santa hats for winter bash ? I don't see any related to Christmas.

Comment: `Major Award`, appearing in one of the most definitively Christmas movies available today, isn't related to Christmas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to "Got a Tablet for Christmas" (already mentioned), there is [Stockings Hung by the Fire](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/stockings-hung-by-the-fire).  Surely the Christmas spirit involves *giving* and not just *getting*, right?

Answer (score 10):

You have the hat

- [Got a tablet for Christmas](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/got-a-tablet-for-christmas)
  post on Christmas day using the Android or iOS app

If you're from Europe you could consider the hat [Kofia](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/kofia) to be a christmas hat as it description states

> first post between 12/26 and 1/1

and 12/26 is [Tweede Kerstdag](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweede_kerstdag) (literally Second Christmas Day)

Comment: I don't see a direct relation between Christmas & Tablet

Comment: It's 'Got a tablet for Christmas' - a popular gift item...use it on Christmas day...to post on SE.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Santa hat, like we had last year.
There is, however, a Christmas-related had: "Got a Tablet for Christmas", for posting via the app on December 25.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to see more Christmas hats! Perhaps a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for [winterbash-2015](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2015) is in order.