# ho-ho-ho hat is missing

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

Last year, I earned the "ho-ho-ho" hat on the 25th December. If I remember correctly, any user could earn it by just logging in on the site on 25 December. This year I waited for 25th December as well so that I could get this hat as well. But when I checked the list of hats, there was no "ho-ho-ho" hat. It's the coolest hat of Winter Bash

Why we don't have that hat this year?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245530/no-hats-related-to-christmas

Comment: We didn't have a Ho-Ho-Ho hat the year before last either. The only hat that isn't new this year is Eureka; Winter Bash tends to have *new hats each year*.

Comment: Why downvotes ? Cant I ask such question ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay. But I liked that hat. That's why I put the question here ^^

Comment: This is meta, downvotes indicate disagreement, not suitability for the site. In this case, people probably just disagree with the premise of your question.

Comment: To put @Kevin's comment into simple words, at least 7 users so far don't think we should get that hat again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's bad that they dont want it again. Anyway Thanks Guys :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not missing; they made a different hat for Christmas this year: [Got a Tablet for Christmas](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/got-a-tablet-for-christmas).
This year's hat for Christmas is earned by posting via the Android or iOS app on a tablet.

EDIT: Another Christmas hat is the "[Stockings by the Fire](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/stockings-hung-by-the-fire)", for starting a bounty on Christmas day.

Note that it's not a Santa hat, either. SE got some new artwork for this year's hats. There are no Santa hats, unless there is one in the secret hats that hasn't been revealed yet. (And if there is, SE, you should call it "Secret Santa" :-) )

Comment: Ah! A substitution jutsu :/ I hate it.!

Comment: Secret Santa ? Sounds like a drag!

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Well, I don't think you have to worry about it... with 2 publicly known hats for activity on Christmas day, I doubt there will be a secret hat for it as well.

Comment: But... I wanted that ho-ho-ho hat only. I dont care if there is any substitute hat. But as I mentioned that hat is the coolest among all.

Comment: :( `There are no Santa hats`

Comment: Well, if @SantaClaus himself says so, then it must be true. I'll put them on my wishlist for next year.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I was merely expressing my disappointment with your statement that there aren't any Santa hats, as I was hopeful. But I'll look forward to your list next year if one doesn't turn up this year.

Comment: @Santa I wanted to say same thing. And in return i got downvotes  :(

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the problem of this year's hat being different, make sure that your 12/25 post has a positive score in order to get the hat.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Milo :)