# Misalign on the extention of keyboard in iPad app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image]

PS: this post is a dupe of another post? I can't see one.

- App Version: 1.4.0.234
- Device: iPad2,2
- OS Version: Version 8.4.1 (Build 12H321)

---

> not enough free-hand red circles...

[image]

Comment: not enough free-hand red circles...

Comment: @rene fixed. See my edit

Comment: I still can't see what is misaligned in the screenshot. Can you explain how you expect it to look?

Comment: I have to redefine circle...

Comment: Is that keyboard drawn by the app? I assumed it was part of ios?

Comment: @ShadowWizard i remember it used to be aligned in the middle, so that it leaves equally space between the top margin and the main keyboard. It's better in UI perspective

Comment: @rene it's an extension of the keyboard. Every app can make its own extension.

Comment: Ah, OK, I wasn't aware of that feature.

Comment: You mean there is no top margin? @rene SE needs it for buttons like image upload, code block etc. :)

Comment: I want my [got an I-Pad for Christmas Hat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245531/158100) this year .... @ShadowWizard

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes

Comment: not enough free-hand red circles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

I rewrote the markdown toolbar recently to use `UIInputView` and to resize its own height rather than rebuild itself on orientation change.  It looks like when the height of the toolbar changed, the input view's background elements get misaligned on iPads running iOS 8.

I initially was going to just apply a solid colored background view in that case, but then I realized (A) there's no reason the toolbar's height should ever change on iPad and (B) the toolbar kind of looks ugly with its small buttons and lopsided margins.  So I added some logic saying if it's an iPad always use certain dimensions and now it looks nicer and functions consistently between all OS versions.

Comment: But different iPad may lead to different keyboard height...

Comment: @Ooker The markdown toolbar isn't part of the keyboard.  It just looks like it and is attached above.  On the iPhone we were resizing toolbar's height to save vertical space in landscape, that's not really a concern on an iPad.