# Make explicit the meaning of "metric" in the iPad app as "collecting your data"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, wording, metrics

As shown in [What is Metrics setting in iPad app used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266772), I don't know what it means. Why not just call the feature "collecting data"?

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. The current wording is bad UX.

Comment: I'd go with "Disable Data Collection".

Comment: @ShadowWizard what's the difference?

Comment: In my opinion "Disable Collecting Data" doesn't sound right, that's all.

Comment: What's the squiggly B letter thing on the app name?

Comment: Oh, and no freehand circles. Outrageous!

Comment: Should probably call it "share usage statistics"

Comment: @Zizouz212 it's the Greek letter of "beta". [I dare you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266770/260800) to ask me freehand circles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm changing to "Analytics" adding a blurb below the setting saying what's turned off.

[image: Screenshot showing new text.]